# FIXED - Change Sharepoint Term IsAvailableForTagging property

Tags: jsom, term-store

I'm trying to change the property "IsAvailableForTagging" to false from some terms using JSOM, but when i try Term.IsAvailableForTagging = false or Term.IsAvailableForTagging = 'false' nothing happens, even errors not appears but still available for tagging. It's possible to change?

Thanks

**I FOUND A SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM.**

```
let context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
let taxonomy = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
let termStores = taxonomy.get_termStores();
let termStore = termStores.getByName('Store Name');
let termSet = termStore.getTermSet('Set Id');
let terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

context.load(terms, 'Include(Id, IsRoot, Labels, TermsCount, Name, PathOfTerm, Parent.Id, Parent.Name, IsAvailableForTagging, TermSet.Name)');

context.executeQueryAsync(()=>{
    const enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
    
    while(enumerator.moveNext()){
         current = enumerator.get_current();

         // current.get_isAvailableForTagging this returns the status os tagging
         current.set_isAvailableForTagging(false) //this worked for me
       
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code? For example, we need to use if you execute the `executeQueryAsync()` function

Comment: Sure, the code is available now, thanks.

Comment: I found a solution, thanks for your atention.